# How to create const array of structs?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm looking for a way to create a constant array of struct.
I tried this one(it'a in a header file):

```
//#pragma once
#ifndef __CANDY_DB_H__
#define __CANDY_DB_H__

#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Candy {
    char Name[16];
    bool Vegan;
}Candies;

const Candies  first = {"Apple",true};

const Candies second = ("Popcorn", true);

const Candies CandiesArray[2] = { first, second };

#endif //__CANDY_DB_H__
```

But it seems to be wrong.

What is the best way to do that?

Comment: Don’t invent names that start with double underscore or with underscore and a capital letter. They are reserved for “the implementation”.  Yes, system headers use the notation; they’re required to do so. You shouldn’t because you can interfere with the implementation, or messed up by the implementation, and it’s your fault.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `CandiesArray` is declared at file scope (outside any function), which implies that it represents an object with static storage duration, which must be initialized by a *constant expression*. Unlike C++, in C `first` is not a constant expression, despite that `const` qualifier.

To remedy this situation, you might put elements directly within the intitializer:

```
const Candies CandiesArray[2] = {
    {"Apple", true},
    {"Popcorn", true}
};
```

Comment: Great, Thanks! Do you know how can I use this constant in a different C file in the same project?

Comment: @s_s: The ordinary approach is to _declare_ an array in header and _define_ it in its source file. For instance, you might put `extern const Candies CandiesArray[];` into `candy_db.h` and `const Candies CandiesArray[2] = {...};` goes to `candy_db.c` (which must include its header at first). Then, you can use `CandiesArray` in other files by including `candy_db.h` header.

Comment: It Works, Thanks!